# How do you create an enumeration of random values?

Tags: c#, .net, random, ienumerable

How can I get an `IEnumerable` of random values? I'm disappointed the class [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts6se2ek) doesn't implement `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: Would randomly generating a bunch of numbers and store them in a list, which implements IEnumerable<T>, fulfill your requirement?

Comment: And I'm disappointed it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<double>`...oh now I see why they didn't implement either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write an **extension method** that will `yield return` new values.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetRandomValues(this Random instance)
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return instance.Next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I made a `GetEnumerator` extension method, will I now be able to `foreach` over an object of type Random?

Comment: Does this mean if you do something like: `var myRandom = new Random(); foreach(int r in myRandom.GetRandomValues()){}` it will loop indefinitely?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - yes. The method gives you an infinite collection of values, you have to decide when to stop reading.

Comment: @JakubKonecki alright, just wanted to make sure. :)  Easy enough to add an overload that lets you specify a total amount of iterations.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - no, just do this: `var myRandom = new Random(); foreach(int r in myRandom.GetRandomValues().Take(100){}`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: BONUS TIME, that overload already exists: `myRandom.GetRandomValues().Take(100)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this yourself fairly easily, for example

```
public IEnumerable<int> RandomInts(int below)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    while (true) yield return r.Next(below);
}
```

Comment: I'd pass in the instance of Random to avoid seeding problems.

Comment: @Code Yeah, that's a good idea... But then my answer would be pretty much the same as Jakub's :p

Answer (score 1):

The some problematic points off having an `IEnumerable<int>` instance for the Random class are

- The random generator has infinitely many elements, therefore using the `foreach` construct or an loop over the elements will never terminate.
- The `IEnumerator<int>` instance which `getEnumerator` from `IEnumerable<int>` should return has a function `Reset` which resets the enumerator to the begin of the collection. Assuming correct behaviour this should return the first generated random number, as it was generated in the past.

The last problem can be solved in at least two ways,

- Keeping an list of already generated values, this might not be very memory efficient, but at least ensures that it will always return the same values after resetting.
- Keeping the starting seed and when `Reset` is called a new generator can be instantiated with the previous seed. All other random generating methods of Random should be hidden to prevent the, from being accessed.

As the bookkeeping method is not very good, I would go for the second version. Which is quite a large class, as you can see below.

```
public class RandomInt : IEnumerable<int>
{
    int seed;

    public RandomInt ()
    {
        seed = new Random ().Next();
    }


    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator ()
    {
        return new InternalEnumerator (seed);
    }

    protected class InternalEnumerator : IEnumerator<int>
    {
        Random randomGen;
        int current;
        int seed;

        protected InternalEnumerator (int seed)
        {
            this.seed = seed;
        }

        #region IEnumerator implementation
        public bool MoveNext ()
        {
            if (randomGen == null)
                randomGen = new Random (seed);
            current = randomGen.Next();
            return true;
        }

        public void Reset ()
        {
            randomGen = null;
        }

        public int Current {
            get {
                if (randomGen == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException ("Enumerator in reset state");
                return current;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```