# Is it a bad practice implementing infinite enumerators and enumerables?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have the following class:

```
class CopyProvider<T> where T: IMyCloneable
{
    private readonly T _original;

    public CopyProvider(T original) => _original = original;

    public T Current { get; private set; }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        Current = _original.Clone();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now I am wondering whether it would be a good practice to declare this class as an implementation of `IEnumerator<T>`. From a syntactical perspective, the `CopyProvider` does meet the requirements, but would it be a violation of the `IEnumerator` semantics?

Alternatively, I also could write the following method:

```
IEnumerable<T> ProvideCopies<T>(T original) where T: IMyCloneable
{
    while(true)
        yield return original.Clone();
}
```

This would be much more comfortable, indeed. But again, I get confrontated the same question: Would this usage of `IEnumerable` break the interface's semantics?

Or should I consider implementing a separate object structure with an `InfiniteEnumerator` and/or an `InfiniteEnumerable`? However, this would preclude me from using C# syntactic sugar like `yield` and `foreach`.

I am looking forward to your recommendations.

Comment: Why/what exactly would be a violation of the interface? Also, `InfiniteEnumerator` makes no sense to me, why would it be infinite?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto *why would it be infinite?* - because `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` never returns false.  A legit use might be the enumerator of random values from [How do you create an enumeration of random values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11435285/3744182).  You could do something like `random.GetRandomValues().TakeWhile(i => (some condition))`.  Anyway this question seems primarily opinion based to me, or maybe a duplicate of [Is an infinite enumerable still “enumerable”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16703285/3744182).

Comment: Related: [MVP-Submitted: Calculating with Infinite Sequences in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20100314131546/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/cc307157.aspx) on MSDN; also archived here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/4/B/54B83DFE-D7AA-4155-9687-B0CF58FF65D7/calculating-with-infinite-sequences.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If your enumeration will never stop producing results, it would be better to require the developer to be explicit about what is the maximum amount to be generated, so that you remove the risk of an infinite loop when the developer uses a `for each` syntax with your enumerable. e.g.

```
IEnumerable<T> ProvideCopies<T>(T original, int howMany) where T: IMyCloneable<T>
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, howMany).Select(x => original.Clone());
}
```

or, if you're old school:

```
IEnumerable<T> ProvideCopies<T>(T original, int howMany) where T: IMyCloneable<T>
{
    for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        yield return original.Clone();
}
```

That way, the developer is **not** obligated to consume the entire enumeration and can stop at any time (i.e you're still *yielding* as you go) but you know it will stop at some point, rather than introduce the possibility of your code blocking forever in production because of a bug in the code.

---

If you truly can't tell how many copies will be needed and need to keep generating copies until something else tells you to stop, then `IObservable<T>` would be better suited for that scenario, as it's intended to be "listening" forever until you `Dispose()` of it.

> [IObservable Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I think it is bad practice indeed. Thread will not be able to process any other code paths. And this can put lot of burden on the processor.

Comment: The question was not whether it is bad to not stop/break enumerating a "countable infinity" ;-) (Also see the links given in dbc's comment to the question)